# python won't recognize the 'tilde / backtick' key

Tags: python-3.x

I want the user to select from a range of possible keys, then display some stuff depending on which key they press.

```
from psychopy import core, visual, event
response_key=event.waitKeys(keyList=['<insert character here>','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0']
if response_key[0][0]==<insert character here>:
     <do some stuff>
```

I've looked for hours and can't figure out why it won't recognize that particular key, no matter what I put it as in 'keyList'.

Comment: What do you mean by Python won't recognize it? It's not in your list. If the key event is not triggered or matched then it's probably your OS or the library that uses a different identifier for that key. Are you on Windows?

Comment: I'm using a python environment called PsychoPy3 on OSX.

Comment: Can you try `K_BACKQUOTE` (according to [this](http://thepythongamebook.com/en:glossary:p:pygame:keycodes))?

Comment: Like, put that in the 'keyList' list? I just tried importing pygame and then referring to K_BACKQUOTE in and out of quotes as the first element in the list. That didn't work, but I'm not sure if that's even what I was supposed to try...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, apparently psychopy calls that 'quoteleft'